# Datadog data validation between on-prem and cloud database

Tags: validation, datadog

Very new to Datadog and need some help. I have crafted 2 SQL queries (one for on-prem database and one for cloud database) and I would like to run those queries through Datadog and be able display the query results and validate that the daily results fall within an expected variance between the two systems.

I have already set up Datadog on the cloud environment and believe I should use DogStatsD to create a custom metric but I am pretty lost with how I can incorporate my necessary SQL queries in the code to create the metric for eventual display on a dashboard. Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to be using the MySQL integration, and configure the 'custom queries' option: https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/faq/how-to-collect-metrics-from-custom-mysql-queries

You can follow those instructions after you configure the base integration https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/mysql/#pagetitle (This will give you a lot of use metrics in addition to the custom queries you want to run)

As you mentioned, DogStatsD is a library you can import to whatever script or application in order to submit metrics. But it really isn't a common practice in the slightest to modify the underlying code of your database. So instead it makes more sense to externally run a query on the database, take those results, and send them to datadog. You could totally write a python script or something to do this. However the Datadog agent already has this capability built in, so it's probably easier to just use that.

---

I am also just assuming SQL refers to MySQL, there are other integration for things like SQL Server, and PostgreSQL, and pretty much every implementation of sql. And the same pattern applies where you would configure the integration, and then add an extra line to the config file where you have the check run your queries.